# Workllght Adapters security

Tags: worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I have 1 worklight project containing 2 applications i want to prevent 1 application from accessing the adapter of another application how can i  do that?
is there any role based authentication in worklight server to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no role management for this.

However, simply put, your application will not be able to use any adapter because you must explicitly put the adapter name and the procedure name of the specific adapter inside your applicative code. The application can only use what you state and nothing else.